# hex to bin in C

Tags: binary, hex

I'm trying to convert hex into bin. If i call bits(0x101) it prints 00011, which is obviously wrong. Im pretty sure its in the for loop. Any ideas??

```
int hextobin (int n){
   char buffer[33];

   if(n==0) {
       putchar('0');
       return 0;
   }

   char *cp = buffer + 32;
   *cp = 0;
   for(int i =0;i <=sizeof(n); i++){
      --cp;
      if(n & 1) *cp = '1';
      else *cp = '0';
      n >>= i;
    }
   printf(cp);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you shift the last `1` bit out of `n`, it becomes a zero, and your loop aborts, even if there's bits left to deal with.

And do yourself a favor... indent your code properly. It's oh-so-much easier to read/debug when it's formatted properly.

Comment: so how do i fix this? do i move that line somewhere else?

Comment: instead of `while (n)`, you should do a for() loop for each bit you want converted. e.g. `for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(n); i++)` or similar. Been a long while since I worked in C, so that won't work as is, but should be enough to get you going.

Comment: `for(int i =0;i <=sizeof(n); i++){
    --cp;
    if(n & 1) *cp = '1';
    else *cp = '0';
    n >>= i;
  }` This is my for loop right now. Still not printing out the right thing.